# Building a priority queue with a minHeap

Tags: c++

This is my first time implementing a priority queue and I have a question.
For this implementation:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
struct PriorityQueue
{
    std::vector<T> heapMin;
    
    PriorityQueue();
    PriorityQueue(std::vector<T>);
    void minHeapfy(int);
    void buildMinHeap();
    void insertElement();
    T priorityMax();
    T priorityExtractMax();
};

template<typename T>
PriorityQueue<T>::PriorityQueue()
{
}

template<typename T>
PriorityQueue<T>::PriorityQueue(std::vector<T> init) : heapMin(init)
{
}

template <typename T>
void PriorityQueue<T>::minHeapfy(int pos)
{
    int st = pos * 2 + 1, dr = pos * 2 + 2;
    int imin = pos;
    if (st < heapMin.size() && heapMin.at(st) < heapMin.at(imin))
    {
        imin = st;
    }
    if (dr < heapMin.size() && heapMin.at(dr) < heapMin.at(imin))
    {
        imin = dr;
    }
    if (imin != pos)
    {
        std::swap(heapMin.at(pos), heapMin.at(imin));
        minHeapfy(imin);
    }
}

template<typename T>
void PriorityQueue<T>::buildMinHeap()
{
    for (int i = heapMin.size() / 2 - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        minHeapfy(i);
    }
}
```

if I do something like this in main()

```
    PriorityQueue<int> test(std::vector<int> {6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1});
    test.buildMinHeap();
    for (int var : test.heapMin)
    {
        std::cout << var << " ";
    }
```

I will get

```
1 2 4 3 5 6
```

it is correct, because it follows the rules of a min Heap - each parent is lower than its children.
But if I use a tree visualisator, such as:

[https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/Heap.html](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Egalles/visualization/Heap.html)

I will get another min heap, probably because the heap is built differently (re-doing the heap each time a new node is inserted)
[image: photo]

Is there any problem with my approach vs inserting each node at a time, as the tree visualisator does?

Is my Priority Queue still valid?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking about. Your code produces a proper heap.

Comment: @SergeyA "Is there any problem with my approach vs inserting each node at a time, as the tree visualisator does?"

Comment: You may be able to use the standard [std::make_heap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) instead of implementing your own.

Comment: You having or not having a problem depends on your goals. If your goal is to match visualisation, than you have a problem, as it doesn't match. If your goal is to produce a minHeap, you do not have a problem.

Comment: @SergeyA My goal is to implement a min-Priority Queue, so I need a min heap for it. I guess I'm fine then?

Comment: Yes, you are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) is a partially sorted structure. A min heap requires only the parent to be smaller than the current node, but puts no restriction on the order of sibling nodes. This means there are many ways to organize the same data in a heap.

The following are both correct min heaps for values 1, 2, 3:

```
    1          1
   / \        / \
  2   3      3   2
```

We can verify correctness by plugging the results into [`std::is_heap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_heap):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<int> x { 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6 };
    vector<int> y { 1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5 };
    cout << is_heap(begin(x), end(x), [](auto a, auto b) { return a > b; }) << endl;
    cout << is_heap(begin(y), end(y), [](auto a, auto b) { return a > b; }) << endl;
}
```

Prints:

```
1
1
```

Hence both your result and the online version are correct.

Answer (score 0):

While your implementation seems to give the correct result, it can be much simplified by using the standard library. Changing the implementation of `buildMinHeap()` as follows you can remove `minHeapfy()`:

```
template<typename T>
void PriorityQueue<T>::buildMinHeap()
{
    std::make_heap(heapMin.begin(), heapMin.end(), std::greater<>{});
}
```

The result of the example case should be:

```
1 2 4 3 5 6
```

To add a new element, use `std::push_heap()` and to remove the first element, use `std::pop_heap()`.